# Problems using Bundle. Unable to find method?

Tags: android, methods, bundle, resolve

I'm trying to use a bundle. But the code gives me some errors.. The paramBundle.open returns with an error : cannot resolve method open(), the method close() does the same for me. 
The AnimationGetNewNumber method cant be resolved either. 
What am I doing wrong ?

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle paramBundle) {
    super.onCreate(paramBundle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_edit_animation);
    getIntent().getExtras();
    if (getIntent().getExtras().getInt("AEA_INT_ACTION", 0) == 0)
    {
        Bundle bundle= new Bundle(paramBundle);
        paramBundle.open();
        this.animationNumber = paramBundle.AnimationGetNewNumber();
        paramBundle.close();
    }
    for (;;)
    {
        this.gridView = ((GridView)findViewById(R.id.gridviewAddEdit));
        this.gridView.setChoiceMode(1);
        this.imageAdapter = new ImageAdapter(this, this.animationNumber);
        this.gridView.setAdapter(this.imageAdapter);
        this.gridView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        this.gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(this);
        return;
        this.animationNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("AEA_INT_NUMBER", 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to retreive data from saved instace bundle then make use of following method in your activity.

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

  this.animationNumber = savedInstanceState.AnimationGetNewNumber();//your code of retriving data from bundle

  Log.i("debug", "saved data: " + myString);
}
```

Note: there is no open() and close() method for bundle instace.

Answer (score 1):

[`Bundle`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html) does not have a method named `open()`, nor a method named `close()`, nor a method named `AnimationGetNewNumber()`. You can't call methods that doesn't exist.